# Which ORM is manageable to use in .Net Web API with Oracle Database?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, oracle11g, orm

This is a Suggestion post.

We are building a mobile financial solution for a bank. We need to use Oracle database and we are planning to go with .Net Web API and Angular.

Which ORM should be manageable and do good in long run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preferences at the moment are Entity Framework and Dapper.

Entity Framework increases the productivity by a lot because you do not have to write raw queries by yourself (you can use LINQ instead).

In some critical parts of the application where performance is crucial, I would probably go with Dapper (only if speed improvement is distinguishable).

Comment: Thanks mate. I would be going with dapper.

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct if it helped you in taking your decision?